# RecyclerView show partial results

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a strange problem filling the RecyclerView properly.
I have a TabLayout with 4 tabs,In the first tab i want to show a list of contacts but it shows only partial results (  3 contacts or not at all)
while my contacts list is about 250.
I have also noticed that at first only the first two tabs are instantiated and if for example i press the third tab and then the first one it shows the expected results.

this is my adapter:

```
public class rvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<rvAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private static List<Contact> contacts;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextViewName;
        public CheckBox mCheckBox;
        public TextView mTextViewNumber;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.mTextViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            this.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_check_box);
            this.mTextViewNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public rvAdapter(List<Contact> contacts) {

        this.contacts = contacts;

        Log.d("TAG","constructor "+contacts.size());
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        CustomViewHolder vh = new CustomViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder,int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        String name = contacts.get(position).getName();
        String number = contacts.get(position).getPhone_number();
        //Boolean status = contacts.get(position).isSelected();
        holder.mTextViewName.setText(name);
        holder.mTextViewNumber.setText(number);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }


}
```

and this is how is set it :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invite, container, false);

    numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    //find done button
    btn_done = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_done);
    //find listview
    rv_invite = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_invite);
    //get contacts list

    setContacts(numbers);
    //sorting the contact list
    Collections.sort(contacts);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    //mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rv_invite.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter 
    mAdapter = new rvAdapter(contacts);

    rv_invite.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

and this is the layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_invite"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_done"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Done" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whats the result of log.d(size) in constructor. Your second problem statement is not clear, does your view load everytime and you do no want that?

Comment: log.d(size) shows 250 results ,but i see only 3 on the view.

Comment: can you please add the layout file which has recycler view that R.layout.fragment_invite to the question

Comment: I have added the layout file @ShadowDroid

Comment: I am sure you must be able to scroll the recyclerview...but to test remove the weight attribute and make the height of RecyclerView as match_parent for now and check whether you can see more than 3 results....Also if you want Button at the bottom of your screen then go for Relative Layout.

Comment: nothing changed,but if change to another tab and then go back to the invite tab i see all records as expected. it looks like it reloads the information within this fragment.

Comment: I have noticed that if i remove my tabs i see results correctly.@ShadowDroid

Comment: Than probably you need to check the layout design properly...I would suggest instead of using weights and linear layout where in you have scrolling...use Relative layout it will help you better